# Default parameter in angular directive

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How I can set a default parameter in angular directive?

**Here is direcitve in html:**

```
<product product="product" isfavorites="true"></product>
```

i want `isfavorites` have a default value `false`. so if is not set to `true` return `false`.
How i can do this?

Comment: What is the code of your directive?

Comment: inside your directive controller or link function, check if isfavourites is undefined or empty and set it to false.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, undefined properties (such as `isfavorite`) are perceived as a false boolean. Inside your directive you should declare the `isfavorite` property which will automatically be false.

```
$scope.isfavorite; //this is undefined, therefore evaluated as false
```

As written in MDN documentation:

> If value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false.

Answer (score 1):

if you defined isfavorite in your directive like this

    `bindToController: {
        isfavorite: '=?'
    },`

and not pass its value, then by default it is undefined which treats as false and if you want to give true as default then you can do something like this

    `controller: function () {
        this.isfavorite = true;
        // your code
    }`

Answer (score 0):

as @gaurav5430 said you can check it in link function. so for this use `attrs` `param` and get that value. if that value is empty so it is `false` else is `true`.

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular
  .module('MyApp', [
  ])
.controller('Main', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
    var self = this;
  
     self.products = [{"productName":"a","id":12},{"productName":"b","id":"34"}];
     self.test = function(name){
       alert(name);
       }
  
}])
.directive('product', ['$compile', function($compile) {  
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            products: '=',
             ngModel : '=',
             isfavorites:'@'
        },
      controller:"Main as myCtrl",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          
          console.log(attrs.isfavorites);
          if(attrs.isfavorites == '')
            alert("false")
            else
              alert("true");
            var template =
                '<ul>' +
                    '<li data-ng-repeat="product in products |filter:{id:ngModel}"  ng-click="myCtrl.test(product.productName)" >' +
                        '{{product.productName}}' +
                    '</li>' +
                '</ul>';

            // Render the template.
            element.html('').append($compile(template)(scope));
        }
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="Main as myCtrl">
      <div>
         <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.pID" />
           <product  products="myCtrl.products " ng-model="myCtrl.pID" isfavorites></product>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply acquire variable at the beginning of the link method of the directive and use `||` pattern like so:

```
directive('product', product);

product.$inject = ['$scope'];

function product($scope){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link
  };

  function link(scope, elmt, attrs){
    var isfavorities = scope.$eval(attrs.isfavorities) || false;

    // || false is written only for verbosity and code clearness because undefined variables, if evaluated, are false by nature.
    // anyway this method is useful when you need default input values quickly
  }
}
```